# Is there a Canon or Legends explanation for "human-cyborg relations"?

Tags: star-wars, c-3po

In *A New Hope*, C-3PO introduces himself to Luke:

> THREEPIO: I see, sir.
>
> LUKE: Uh, you can call me Luke.
>
> THREEPIO: I see, sir Luke.
>
> LUKE: (laughing) Just Luke.
>
> THREEPIO: And I am See-Threepio, **human-cyborg relations**, and this is my counterpart, Artoo-Detoo.
>
> <sub>(Source: https://imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-A-New-Hope.html, emphasis added)</sub>

C-3PO describes himself the same way in many other Star Wars works, including *The Rise of Skywalker*. This is a bit odd since cyborgs are just organic beings with cybernetic parts, and generally don't need help communicating with humans. I've looked through some of my reference books and haven't been able to find anything official addressing this, so my question is: **do any Legends or Canon sources explain what it means for C-3PO to specialize in "human-cyborg relations"?**

(The older question "[C3PO: a cyborg?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5791/21154)" asks about this, but seems more focused on parsing his statement than finding sources. There are plenty of ways the phrase could be read, but I'm interested in official confirmation.)

Comment: I always took it as Human/Cyborg relations. As in he was designed to interact with both.

Comment: Any decent answer for this question could simply be copy-pasted onto the other question you've highlighted. If you feel the answers there are lacking, rather than posting a duplicate, the thing to do is to post a bounty

Comment: This was foreshadowing that Luke would eventually become a cyborg.

Comment: @Valorum Done, thanks - I'd missed that questions with accepted answers can be bountied.